# Is it possible to arrange response of a fulltext lucene in couchdb?

Tags: json, lucene, couchdb

I have an fulltext lucene search in couchdb, but the problem is it gives only is as response. I want to alter the response. Is it possible or not?

```
{
   "_id": "_design/foo",
   "_rev": "4-90b71100ac746407a05b504926d64dbb",
   "fulltext": {
       "by_subject": {
           "index": "function(doc) { var ret=new Document(); ret.add(doc.subject); return ret }"
       },
       "by_content": {
           "index": "function(doc) { var ret=new Document(); ret.add(doc.content); return ret }"
       }
   }
}
```

I am requesting with the below curl,

```
http://localhost:5984/sample/_fti/_design/foo/bysubject?q=mysub
```

Currently i got result as:

> {"q":"default:sub","fetch_duration":0,"total_rows":1,"limit":25,"search_duration":1,"etag":"43b7427c462d","skip":0,"rows":[{"score":6.782285690307617,"id":"001"}]}

Actually I need to add some more details in response like:

> {"q":"default:sub","fetch_duration":0,"total_rows":1,"limit":25,"search_duration":1,"etag":"43b7427c462d","skip":0,"rows":[{"score":6.782285690307617,"id":"001","sub":"mysub","detail":"mydetails"}]}

Comment: me also searching for same solution

Comment: Does calling it with `include_docs=true` works? e.g. `http://localhost:5984/sample/_fti/_design/foo/bysubject?q=mysub&include_docs=true`

Comment: it works, but i need to customize the result. for example i need to display only some fields in result and need to append some extra string in result.